# ¿Por qué al poner una etiqueta <h> sale como si fuera un link?

Tags: html, css

Os dejo aquí el código y una captura de pantalla de lo que me sale al abrirlo con el navegador (Firefox):

```
        <style>
        .headerEnd{
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color:#000000;
            height:100px;
        }
        #fotoEndi{
            margin-left: 100px;
        }

        @font-face{
            font-family: "TituloEndi";
            src: url("GameofBrush.ttf");
        }
        a:link{
            text-decoration:none;

        }
        a:visited{
            color: #000000;
        }

        #nombreEndi{
            text-align: center;
            margin:0 auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            color: #8B0000; 
            font-family: "TituloEndi";
            font-size:40px;
        }

        .header{
            height:100px; width:100%;
            text-align:center;
        }

        .menu{
            height: 37px;
            width:100%;
            background-color: #B22222; 
            color:#333; 
            text-align:center;
            box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0)
        }
        .wrapper{ height:2000px; 
           width:100%; 
           padding-top:20px
        }
        .menu-fixed {
            position:fixed;
            z-index:1000;
            top:0;
            width:100%;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
        }
        ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: inline-block; 
            font-size: 25px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        body{
            background-color: #DCDCDC;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #menu li{
            background: #DCDCDC;
            display: inline-block;
            list-style: none;
            background-color:#B22222;
        }

        .listaArriba{
            color:  #000000;
            width: 150px;
        }

        #titulua{
                background-color:#000;
                text-align:center;
                margin-left: 300px;
                margin-top: 7px;
        }

        .seccion1{
            background-color: white;
            height:749px;
            width: 1350px;
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
        #footer{
            margin-top:0px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color:#B22222;
        }

        #soundcloud{
            margin-right:40px;
            margin-top: 3px;
        }
        .navigationFoot{
            text-align: right;
        }
        #creditos{
            font-size:12px;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        a{
            color:black;
        }
        #o{
            margin-left: 250px;
            float: top;
        }

        .videos{
            height: 1000px;
            width: 1000px;
            background-color: white;
            margin-left: 200px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #oneMoreShot{
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }


    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.carousel').carousel();
            var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;
            $(window).on('scroll',function(){
                if ( $(window).scrollTop() > altura ){
                    $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed');
                } else {
                    $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
                }
            });
            $("#news").mouseover(function(){
                $("#news").css("background-color", "#800000");
                $("#a").css("color",black);
            });

            $("#conciertos").mouseover(function(){
                $("#conciertos").css("background-color", "#800000");
            });         

            $("#songs").mouseover(function(){
                $("#songs").css("background-color", "#800000");
            });             

            $("#lyrics").mouseover(function(){
                $("#lyrics").css("background-color", "#800000");
            });

            $("#store").mouseover(function(){
                $("#store").css("background-color", "#800000");
            });

            $(".listaArriba").mouseleave(function(){
                $(".listaArriba").css("background-color","#B22222");
                $("#videos").css("background-color", "#800000");
            });
            $("#videos").css("background-color", "#800000");
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="headerEnd">
        <div class = "cabecera">
            <ul id = "lista1">
                <a href="home.html" id="fotoEndi"><img src="endikasangroniz.png" id=titulua></a>
                <a href="../EndiIngles/endi.html" id = "o"><img src="../Bandera/uk.png"></a>
                <a href="../EndiCastellano/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/banderaEspana.png"></a>
                <a href="../EndiEuskera/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/ikurrina.png"></a>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <header class = "header">
        <div class="menu" id="menu">
            <nav class="top-menu">
                <ul class = "navigation">
                    <li class="listaArriba" id="news"><a href="eventos.html">NEWS</a></li>
                    <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="">GIGS<a></li>
                    <li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="">VIDEOS<a></li>
                    <li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="">MUSIC<a></li>
                    <li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="">LYRICS<a></li>
                    <li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">STORE<a></li>
                </ul>
            <nav>
        </div>

            <div class="videos">
                <h2> ONE MORE SHOT </h2>
                <iframe width="750" height="442" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xErYAGUgCjQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="oneMoreShot"></iframe>
            </div>


            <div id="footer">
                <ul class = "navigationFoot">
                    <a id="n" href="https://es-es.facebook.com/EndikaSangroniz/" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png" ></a>
                    <a id="n" href="https://www.instagram.com/endikasangroniz/?hl=es" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
                    <a id="n" href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank"><img id="soundcloud" src="../IconosRedes/bandcamp.png"></a>
                </ul>

        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Lo que sale:
[image: ONE MORE SHOT sería el título que quiero que aparezca normal]

Me gustaría saber porque sale como si fuera un link o algo parecido. Sé que se puede arreglar con CSS con:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

Pero me gustaría saber si existe alguna otra manera de hacerlo para quitarlo que no implique añadir más código. Lo normal creo que es que aparezca la letra en negro y sin subrayar nada sin la necesidad de añadir nada de código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu error es simple, no estás cerrando las etiquetas `<a>` en estas líneas

```
<li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="">GIGS<a></li>
<li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="">VIDEOS<a></li>
<li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="">MUSIC<a></li>
<li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="">LYRICS<a></li>
<li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">STORE<a></li>
```

Debería ser así:

```
<li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="">GIGS</a></li>
<li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="">VIDEOS</a></li>
<li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="">MUSIC</a></li>
<li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="">LYRICS</a></li>
<li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
```

Tampoco estás cerrando `<nav class="top-menu">`, debes revisar muy bien tu código, las aperturas y cierres de etiquetas son fundamentales para mantener una buena estructura.